# Delete occurrences of an element if it occurs more than n times - my own code

Tags: arrays, loops

```
function deleteNth(arr,n){
    let a = [];
    let num_string;
    arr.forEach(function(num) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
            if (num === arr[i]) {
                num_string++;
            }
            if (num_string  < n+1) {
                a.push(num);
            }
        }
    });
    return a;
    a.length = 0;
}
```

I have to created a program that returns a new array without the array variable and that returns more than n times. The computer returns an error.

Comment: Which error is shown?

Comment: no but the computer didnt print anythings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would solve your problem. I included some comments, please reply if you would like further clarifications.

```js
function filterOccurrences(arr, n) {
  // Object to store occurrences of values
  const occ = {};

  // Return array after filter
  return arr.filter(val => {
    // If occurances object already contains current value
    if (occ[val]) {
      // Add +1 count to number of occurances of value
      occ[val]++;
    } else {
      // Else add key with count 1
      occ[val] = 1;
    }

    // Return boolean whether to include current value or not
    return occ[val] <= n;
  });
}

const sample = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];

console.log(filterOccurrences(sample, 2));
// => [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 ]
```

There are a few problems with the code you have provided, for example `a.length = 0;` will never be reached because it's below the return statement.

**Explanation**

`occ` is a javascript `object` that stores values by named keys, if your unsure of how they work, [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a method that loops through each value of an array and expects to be returned either `true` or `false` for each value. If the result is `true`, the value will be kept, else ignored.

So when we loop through each value, we first check if `occ` has a key by name of that value. For example, for value `1` we would check if `occ.1` exists, but since the value is in an array we access it by wrapping the array in brackets, as `occ[val]`. If it does not exist, we give the occurrences object a key by that name and assign it a value of 1, since it's the first occurrence. But if we found that the value already has a key in the `occ` object, we instead increase that value by 1 with the `++` operator. So a second occurrence would increase the count to 2, third to 3, etc.

Lastly we return the result of testing if the count of occurrences are less then or equal to `n` (the max occurrences allowed). If above, will return false and the value will be not be kept in the array.

Comment: i am stil a little bit new in javescript and i didnt completly understand what did you do with the if condition below the filter function, the occ object was not understandable for me too.

Comment: I will provide deeper explanation in post above.